# Partial specialization for pointers, c++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, partial-specialization

How to make partial specialization of the class GList so that it is possible to store pointers of I (i.e I*) ?

```
template <class I>
struct TIList
{
    typedef std::vector <I> Type;
};


template <class I>
class GList
{
      private:
            typename TIList <I>::Type objects;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to specialise to allow that. It can store pointers already.

```
GList<int*> ints;
```

Anyway, if you wanted to specialise GList for pointers, use the following syntax.

```
template <class I>
class GList<I*>
{
    ...
};
```

Then just use `I` as you would in any normal template. In the example above with `GList<int*>`, the pointer specialisation would be used, and `I` would be `int`.

Comment: And the specialized class GList<I*> must have own implementation of the private data member objects?

Comment: Yes, the specialisation shares nothing with the original base template. You have to write all the member variables and member functions again (or factor them out into a common base class if possible).

Comment: I need a different code inside a method processing ponters. I tried to specialize only method for pointers: void GList<I> method (){...} and void GList <I*> method {...}. But compiler does not recognize differences between them....

Comment: Yeah, you can't specialise individual member functions of a template class, you have to specialise the whole class. The usual workaround is to take all the common parts shared between the two into a common base class and have them both inherit from it.

Answer (score 5):

Previous post states that you don't NEED to specialize for pointer types, but you might.

Consider the following:

```
struct Bar {
    void bar(void) { /* do work */ }
};

template <class T> struct Foo {
    T t;

    void foo(void)
    {
        t.bar(); // If T is a pointer, we should have used operator -> right?
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Foo<Bar *> t;

    t.foo();
}
```

This won't compile. Because in Foo::foo we have a pointer yet we use it as variable.

If you add the following, it will use the specialization and compile fine:

```
// This is a pointer to T specialization!
template <class T> class Foo<T *> {
    T * t;
public:
    void foo(void)
    {
        t->bar();
    }
};
```

Comment: That's a really, really bad idea. You should *never* change semantics in a specialisation. When you do that, you end up with things like `std::vector<bool>`. What happens if I use `Foo` with an `std::shared_pointer<T>`? It's not going to use reference semantics, so are you going to specialise for all conceivable smart pointers as well?

Comment: Down-vote only because you think this is a (really really) bad idea? This is a valid case of when a specialization is needed, what you are talking about is a design issue.