# How to handle misses in a C++ HashMap get(key) function?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference, hashmap

I implemented a hashmap in C++ in order to learn more about associative maps in general, and everything works nicely except for one sticking point -- I want the programmer to be able to create maps with arbitrary parametrization (e.g. [using `std::string` for example] `HashMap<string,string*>`, `HashMap<string,string>`, and `HashMap<string*,string>` etc. are all legal).

The trouble is that in the `HashMap::get(int key_data)` function the returned map Value on a miss (where the given Key does not match any mapped Values) can't simply be `NULL` if I support having objects as map Values. I could have the `get(...)` function always return a pointer to the parametrized map Value type, but if that type is already a pointer I can't use the unary `&` operator, and if it is an object I have to use the `&` operator. I definitely don't want to use RTTI, so the question is as follows:

**How can I allow for both object and pointer-to-object return types from my `HashMap::get()` function, which is also required to allow for misses?**

Bear in mind I am using gcc 4.7 with C++11 switched on, so all C++11 features and caveats apply. Below follows my `HashMap::get()` function so far using an 'always return a pointer to whatever value_data happens to be' paradigm:

```
template <class key_data,class value_data> value_data*  
HashMap<key_data,value_data>::get(key_data dk) {

    int key = keyGen(dk);

    int hash_val = HashFunc(key);
    HashNode* entry = _table[hash_val];

    while (entry != 0) {
        if (entry->getCurrentKey() == key) {

            //value_data val = entry->getCurrentValue(); //this temporary will be 
            //gone from the stack quickly and therefore the returned pointer to a 
            //pointer (if value_data is a pointer) will segfault

            return &(entry->getCurrentValue()); //this should be legal and yield 
            //a pointer to a pointer (iff value_data was a pointer), but instead 
            //I get a compiler error claiming 
            //operator & requires an lvalue operand...
        }

        entry = entry->next();

    }

    printf("Your get of int key %i resulted in no hits."
           "The returned pointer to Value is NULL!\n",key);


    return NULL;
}
```

As the comments state, the line `return &(entry->getCurrentValue());` throws a compiler error stating that operator `&` requires an lvalue operand. I can get rid of that error by placing a `value_data` temporary onto the stack, but that will lead to a segfault when I actually try to use it because the returned pointer will be invalid almost instantly. Simply using references to abstract away the syntax issue doesn't work either because in that case misses could not be implemented via return `NULL` (ISO requires that references, unlike raw pointers, point to valid lvalues).

If anyone has a suggestion regarding handling a returned reference that may be 'invalid' (like a dummy object that can be queried for validity that everything else inherits from), I'm open to those as well.

Comment: Why don’t you have a look at how the standard library solves this?

Comment: "I get a compiler error claiming operator & requires an lvalue operand..." I bet `getCurrentValue` returns by value (or a pointer)? If so, it returns a prvalue. To make it compile, make it return a reference. (That won't solve the underlying problem, though.)

Comment: getCurrentValue() returns whatever value_data was parametrized as; could be an object or a pointer (I'm not supporting references because they don't easily allow for 'misses' as defined above)

Comment: @CCJ Well in your example, `getCurrentValue` is only called when the entry exists, right? So it could return a reference.

Comment: @CCJ: Look at the erroneous line of code in this way: `sometype *x = entry->getCurrentValue();  return &x;`    Do you see the problem now?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm searching for an unordered_map implementation, but I keep finding only header files; is it generally header-only? One such unordered_map header file is here: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/unordered_map is that the entire implementation or should there be more?

Comment: @JimR I understand the error reported, I'm just not sure what a viable alternative might be.

Comment: @DyP I suppose I could have getCurrentValue always return a reference and still have get() return a pointer, derived from the returned reference on a hit or given as NULL on a miss.  Of course that still doesn't solve the problem of supporting both pointers and objects as initial parameters given to the HashMap... how would returning a reference in getCurrentValue work if value_data was already a pointer? Could the compiler sort that out, executing an implicit address-of if value_data was an object and just taking value_data if it was a pointer?

Comment: @CCJ `unordered_map` can be implemented header-only, and I guess it is for many implementations of the Standard Library. But it isn't necessary to look at an implementation to see [what the Standard Library specifies](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at). -- As I said earlier, the reference issue doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @CCJ It’s long enough, what more do you expect? It’s the full implementation – however, standard library implementations aren’t very readable, even if you have a lot of experience in C++. I was actually suggesting just to look at the documentation, which makes it clear how missing values are handled.

Comment: @DyP so if I'm understanding that documentation correctly, the standard lib basically cheats by using the same operator for insertion and access, silently creating a Value iff one didn't exist in the map already at the given Key and otherwise returning a reference to said Value?  That's quite clever, I guess, but what if I don't want to perform an automatic insertion or throw an exception if no Value was mapped to the given Key?  I'm imagining use cases like if(myHashMap.get("some_key") != NULL){...do something...} Else{...do something else...}  Not the best pattern ever, but it does come up

Comment: @CCJ The Standard Library associative containers create a new value via the default-ctor if you use `operator[]` and the key cannot be found. In any case, a valid reference is returned. This allows `my_map[key] = something;` no matter if the element exists beforehand. You can use the `at` member function (or `find`) for "bounds-checking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to tackle this would be partial template specialization. For an example how to do this for pointers, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764188/partial-specialization-for-pointers-c).

Basically (copied from the answer there), you'll need

```
template <class I>
class GList<I*>
{
    ...
};
```

to provide a specialized version of a list for any pointer type.

Comment: hmm, so something like 'template <class key_data, class value_data> class HashMap<value_data>{...handle mapped objects here};' and 'template <class key_data, class value_data> class HashMap<value_data*>{...handle mapped pointers here};'?  How would the compiler handle situations where HashMap was parametrized with a pointer in the value_data slot to begin with (HashMap<string,string*>) -- is it smart enough to identify the data type for value_data as std::string and then check whether a pointer or reference operator is also applied to generate the proper code to handle objects versus pointers?

Comment: I'll experiment with this and write back shortly; thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: right, with a little massage and help from the comments above this worked.  Thanks!